# apt-get can install a package, why a library is not found when I build the source?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, radius, freeradius

I installed freeradius 2.1.12 to my ubuntu machine:

```
apt-get install freeradius
```

Then I downloaded its source,

```
apt-get source freeradius
```

build the source:

```
cd freeradius-2.1.12+dfsg
./configure --prefix=/root/freeradius/freeradius-2.1.12
make
```

make fails:

```
        /root/freeradius-2.1.12+dfsg/src/lib/libfreeradius-radius.la -lnsl -lresolv  -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto
gcc -shared  .libs/eapcommon.o .libs/eapcrypto.o .libs/eapsimlib.o .libs/fips186prf.o  -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/root/freeradius-2.1.12+dfsg/src/lib/.libs -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/root/freeradius/freeradius-2.1.12/lib /root/freeradius-2.1.12+dfsg/src/lib/.libs/libfreeradius-radius.so -lnsl -lresolv -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto  -Wl,-soname -Wl,libfreeradius-eap-2.1.12.so -o .libs/libfreeradius-eap-2.1.12.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then I wonder how come "apt-get install" can work, so I checked:

```
#type freeradius
freeradius is hashed (/usr/sbin/freeradius)

# ldd /usr/sbin/freeradius
        libfreeradius-radius-2.1.12.so => /usr/lib/freeradius/libfreeradius-radius-2.1.12.so (0x00007f3d6d1df000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f3d6c735000)
```

So libcrypto and libssl both exist at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.

Then how can I instruct configure to take /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu?

A more general question - if a package can be installed, what is the easiest way to build it from source? Can I somehow download a build script?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're already using a package source, it's really easy: you're missing the development packages needed to build it. There might still be some other mandatory packages missing for a standard minimal package build environment. So first:

```
# apt-get install build-essential fakeroot devscripts
```

then for the package itself:

```
# apt-get build-dep freeradius
```

You'll notice that for each `libfooX` package needed to install the result, it will fetch as well `libfoo-dev` needed to build it,and most often, many more packages. Because the *development* libraries, as well as corresponding include files are packaged separately from the corresponding *runtime* libraries.

You can build back the package by running something like this in the new directory:

```
$ dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -rfakeroot -b
```

If you didn't even need to alter anything then it can be combined into:

```
$ apt-get --build source freeradius
```

The package building won't require root access as long as the package `fakeroot` is installed. It can and should be done as a normal user. Other useful package: `debian-keyring` for Debian or `ubuntu-keyring` for Ubuntu which will be used by `apt-get` to validate the source download the same way  `apt-get` validates a package download by using the contents of  `debian-archive-keyring` or `ubuntu-archive-keyring`.

Just replace "freeradius" with any other package for the general case.
You should really consult the [debian building tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial) explaining all this.